# Is it possible to listen for selectedIndex change?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, selectedindex

I am looking for a way (or a workaround) to subscribe for `selectedIndex` changing (on `<select>` element) when the change done by a simple assignment (like `myElement.selectedIndex=1`).

```
<select id = "mySelect" onchange="myListener()">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
</select>

<script>
    function myListener() {
        console.log('Yes, I hear...'); // doesn't work on selectedIndex assignment
    }
    document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex = 1;
</script>
```

Seems it's not possible, but maybe there is some workaround.
`dispatchEvent` is not an option (the listener attachment must be done from outside).

---

My only solution so far, very similar to @jren510 (but I like his solution more).

```
function myListener() {
    console.log('Yes, I hear...');
}

const originalPropDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLSelectElement.prototype, 'selectedIndex');

Object.defineProperty(HTMLSelectElement.prototype, 'originalSelectedIndex', originalPropDescriptor);

Object.defineProperty(HTMLSelectElement.prototype, 'selectedIndex', {
    get() {
        return this.originalSelectedIndex;
    },

    set(value) {
        myListener();
        this.originalSelectedIndex = value;
    }
});
```

I would like to avoid overriding native methods, by so far it's the only way I see.

Comment: `dispatchEvent` is the only option. What do you mean by _“the listener attachment must be done from outside”_? I assume you’ve read posts similar to [Trigger change event by changing selectedIndex of select without jQuery](/q/60687460/4642212). What doesn’t work with `document.getElementById("mySelect").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));`?

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onchange` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: @SebastianSimon the problem is that I can not know when the assignment (to selectedIndex) is done, so I can not know when to call dispatchEvent. I'm working on kind of library. (and the inline event is just in purpose of MRE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the best answer, but you did mention workarounds..

You can try overriding the setter for the object for which you are trying to detect the change in.

```js
let mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

const callback = () => {
    console.log("Yes, I hear...");
};

const original = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
    Object.getPrototypeOf(mySelect),
    "selectedIndex"
);
Object.defineProperty(mySelect, "selectedIndex", {
    set: function (t) {
        callback();
        return original.set.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    get: function () {
        return original.get.apply(this);
    }
});

let myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
myButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    mySelect.selectedIndex = 1;
});
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
</select>

<button id="myButton"> change selector value to 1 </button>
```

It's worth mentioning that the callback does not run when manually changing the select here.. if you want to preserve that behavior, you can add an event listener that calls `callback` as usual, though there may exist a better solution that captures both cases.

Comment: The best (and the only :) ) solution so far. I did something similar (I will post it also), but seems that yours one is better.